# Detecting if a module has changed

Tags: python, c++

I have a command-line editor to execute python commands, something similar to IDLE. Using the following definitions a module is created (only once) for the editor:

```
static struct PyMethodDef CommandEditorMethods[] = { 
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL } 
};

static struct PyModuleDef CommandEditorModuleDef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "CommandWindow",
    "Command Window Module",
    -1,
    CommandEditorMethods,
};


m_Module = PyModule_Create(&CommandEditorModuleDef);
```

Now when user executes a command such as `>>a=1` it is possible to find all info on variable `a` from module's dictionary.

What I want to do is to find a way to detect if a variable has been added/deleted/updated from this module from C++ side so that I can fire an event and do some other processing on C++ side. The dictionary is changed whenever user creates some value, either from Python side (using an app) or from C++ side by executing a command. How to detect if the module's dictionary has been changed?

Comment: Please provide more details since it is not clear what are you trying to achieve. Are you trying to do observer pattern on some python variable? Who should be notified? python code or C++ code? Are you trying observe that python code was modified outside of your program? Or something else?

Comment: Added more info to address your questions.

Comment: Probably the cheapest way of doing it is check `Py_ssize_t PyDict_Size(PyObject *p)` in idle time and compare with the previous size and take action accordingly.